# Setting HTTPS in functional tests for Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony-1.4, functional-testing

I'm forcing users into SSL using a filter. However, I'm running into issues with the functional tests and particularly redirects not being HTTPS but HTTP which adds in an extra redirect that isn't helpful for testing purposes.

Is there a way to set the functional test browser to use HTTPS by default instead of HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the `sfBrowser` class which is the browser used by the functional tests in Symfony 1.4. I think you could use something like:

```
$browser->setVar('HTTPS', true);
```

whenever you instantiate the browser.

You could also create your own browser class which will inherit from the `sfBrowser` (or `sfTestBrowser`) and set the `HTTPS` to be always true.